# React native: Is it possible to set initial position to SectionList without using scrollToLocation

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I want to set an initial list position (SectionList) without using scrollToLocation.
Is that possible? tried to look it up but couldn't fund anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

A solution I can think of is that you set `initialNumToRender`, which has that initial position in it. But this would cause memory issues when dealing with a large list.

Another workaround would be showing a loader above the list and use `scrollToLocation` without animation. Then hide the loader.